I am using python to read a file encoded in UTF-8 but this still displays wrong garbled text
class TextView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def set_text(self, file_path):
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):  # if the filepath links to a single file AND this part is right
            try:
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    text_content = f.read()
                    self.text.setText(text_content)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        elif os.path.isdir(file_path):  ** if the filepath links to a folder** 
            file_list_html = []
            file_list = os.listdir(file_path)
            for file in file_list:  
                file_path_full = os.path.join(file_path, file)  
                if file.endswith(".txt") and os.path.isfile(file_path_full):
                    file_list_html.append(f"<a href='{file_path_full}'>{file}</a>")  
*this could work but after I clicked the link ,the text would be garbled*
                    #  file_list_html.append(file_path_link)
            file_list_str = "<br>".join(file_list_html)
            self.text.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
            self.text.setHtml(file_list_str)
            self.text.anchorClicked.connect(self.open_link)
        else:
            print(f"{file_path} is not a file or directory")

    def open_link(self, url):
        file_path = QtCore.QUrl.toLocalFile(url)
        if file_path.endswith(".txt"):
            try:
                # encoding = self.detect_encoding(file_path)
                # print(encoding)  
# strange things: this print seems not working , it doesn't show anything in the terminal 
                with open(file_path, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
                    text_content = f.read()
                    self.text.setText(text_content)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    def detect_encoding(file_path):
        try:
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                rawdata = f.read()
                result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
                print(result['encoding'])
                return result['encoding']
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

showing the list of files in folder:

after i clicked the link:

I used the chardet(the detect_encoding function above) to detect the encoding or i just simply set it to utf-8 but none worked
original txt file is in utf-8:


Can you please provide a more comprehensive [mre] and the content of that file? Also, you should use setPlainText(), not setText() (which tries to guess the content type, but may also be wrong).

When I extract the data (using OCR) from the last image and save it as UTF-8, chardet has no problem detecting the encoding. The data I extracted is this: b'\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe5\x88\xb0\xe6\x8d\x86\xe5\xb8\xa6\r\n\xe6\xa3\x80\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe5\x88\xb02\xe6\x8d\x86\xe5\xb8\xa6\xe6\x95\xb0\xe7\x9b\xae\r\n\xe6\x97\xb6\xe9\x97\xb4:2024_04_12_12_33_18\r\n' (which Google Translate detects as Chinese). This implies that the files on your system must have been corrupted somehow. You may think they are encoded as UTF-8 - but in fact they contain mojibake.
